# Store a mysql statement into a variable I can pass to a html form

Tags: php, mysql

I've looked at 10+ examples on here, but most are mysql instead of mysqli or I just can't figure it out.

How would I store this statement into a variable. The variable is going to be called in a seperate html file that contains a form and a Nickname input field.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT adminlogin.Nickname FROM adminlogin 
INNER JOIN coin ON adminlogin.ProfileID=coin.ProfileID");
```

Comment: If you're using PDO, then include that keyword in your searches.

Comment: You are preparing the query, but you are not executing it.  If you want the function to be run, you need to execute it.  Then once you execute it, you can return the results-> look at an example here-> https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_array.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use `include` or `require`.  Like this:

query.php

```
<?php
    $query = "SELECT adminlogin.Nickname FROM adminlogin INNER JOIN coin ON adminlogin.ProfileID=coin.ProfileID";
?>
```

Then in your phtml file, include it like this:

```
<html>
    <header>
        ...SOMETHING...
    </header>
    <body>
        ...SOMETHING...
        <?php
            // when you reach the section that uses the database
            require_once("query.php");

            $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);

            // use your statement...
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

you can read on `require`, `require_once`, `include`, `include_once` to see the differences.  For something like this, I prefer `require_once`.

Lastly, *DO NOT* use mysql* functions!  Take the time to learn PDO.

This will get you started: https://www.w3schools.com/php7/default.asp
Make sure to read, research, test, learn.